# Unregister browser layer

Tags: plone

In one Plone site I removed one product but the it's browser layer keeps registered (raising some exceptions in the log)

```
2015-09-10T06:00:32 WARNING OFS.Uninstalled Could not import class 'ICollectiveMailchimp' from module 'collective.mailchimp.interfaces'
```

I tried to remove this layer using the `plone.browserlayer.utils.unregister_layer`, but it send me the `KeyError` exception:

```
>>> pprint(utils.registered_layers())
[.
 .
 .
 <InterfaceClass collective.mailchimp.interfaces.ICollectiveMailchimp>,
 <InterfaceClass collective.liveblog.interfaces.IBrowserLayer>,
 <InterfaceClass collective.blueline.interfaces.IBrowserLayer>]
>>> layer = utils.registered_layers()[-3]
>>> layer
<InterfaceClass collective.mailchimp.interfaces.ICollectiveMailchimp>
>>> layer.__name__
'ICollectiveMailchimp'
>>> utils.unregister_layer(layer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cartacapital/cartacapital.portal.buildout/eggs/plone.browserlayer-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/plone/browserlayer/utils.py", line 38, in unregister_layer
    raise KeyError("No browser layer with name %s is registered." % name)
KeyError: 'No browser layer with name <InterfaceClass collective.mailchimp.interfaces.ICollectiveMailchimp> is registered.'
>>> utils.unregister_layer(layer.__name__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cartacapital/cartacapital.portal.buildout/eggs/plone.browserlayer-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/plone/browserlayer/utils.py", line 38, in unregister_layer
    raise KeyError("No browser layer with name %s is registered." % name)
KeyError: 'No browser layer with name ICollectiveMailchimp is registered.'
```

do I need to register again this layer before unregister it?

Comment: You must always provide an uninstall profiles also for browser layers: see http://blog.keul.it/2013/05/how-to-make-your-plone-add-on-products.html (browserlayer.xml section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh.. I was using the wrong name to unregister it.. this solved my problem:

```
utils.unregister_layer(name='collective.mailchimp')
```

thank you